# Static variable getting initialized as undefined in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am bit new to Typescript and node.js. I have few variables declared as static in a class, which will be initialized on calling a function. I am trying to access them in another class. Sometimes undefined is getting returned when trying to access those static variables, even though they are initialized. Please find my code below:

Test.ts

```
describe('Test', function () {

let testUtil: TestUtil,

before(async function () {
        await Constants.init_TestConfig();
        testUtil = new TestUtil();
    });

it('Step 1', async function () {
        //Constants.sURL returning the initialized variable
        let url = await Constants.sURL;
        console.log(url);
        await testUtil.loadURL();
    });

});
```

TestUtil.ts

```
export class TestUtil{

public async loadURL(){
        //Constants.sURL returing undefined here
        let url = await Constants.sURL;
        console.log(url);
    }
}
```

Constants.ts

```
export class Constants{

public static sURL:string;

public static async init_TestConfig(){
    //initialize URL
    this.sURL = "some URL";
    }
}
```

`Constants.sURL` when tried to access from `Test.ts` is working fine, but when I tried to access the same from any other class it is returning undefined. The same is with any other variable declared in `Constants.ts` file.

Comment: `this.sURL` is the instance sUrl - i.e it would be `testUtil.sUrl` in your code , not the static `sUrl` - i.e. `Constants.sUrl` - so you're initialising the wrong thing

Comment: ``sURL`` us initialized as static in ``Constants.ts``, not ``TestUtil.ts``. So I am referring to sURL as ``Constants.sURL`` in other classes and ``this.sURL`` in ``Constants.ts``.

Comment: correct, and that's what you are doing incorrectly - try referring to it as `Constants.sURL` in `init_TestConfig` as well - as that is what it is

Comment: I have tried using ``Constants.sURL`` as well, but still it is returning ``undefined`` in ``loadURL()`` method. But the same works fine in ``Test.ts`` file i.e., it is returning the initialized value, not ``undefined``

Comment: if you want to initialise `Constants.sURL` rather than the sUrl property of an **instance of** `class Constants`, then yes, you need to initialise the property that you want to initialise - not one that is something else - just try it and rejoice

Comment: Tried replacing ``this.sURL`` with ``Constants.sURL``, still facing the same issue.